# the image is not compressed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

the image is not compressed Im using the following code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
_backgroundImageView.image = newImage;
```

Comment: you need to make smaller the the image size ?

Comment: I need to  place the image in image view. Image view is  in storyboard. not created by programmatically.

Comment: and i need to place the image in image view but image view is placed in storyboard. image does not loose their originality for whatever simulator and  imageview....

Comment: okay, so what means the **image not compressed** here ?

Comment: yes, your meaning is correct...

Comment: still not getting what you trying to do, you confused me.

Comment: image is not compressed when imageview is created in storyboard .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compress the image

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"];
NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
NSInteger imgSizeBytes = [postData length];
double imgSizeKBytes = ceil((double)imgSizeBytes / 1024);
NSString *strBytes;
if(imgSizeKBytes > 1024) {
    double imgSizeMBytes = (double)imgSizeKBytes / 1024;
    strBytes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB", imgSizeMBytes];
}
else {
    strBytes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d KB", (int)imgSizeKBytes];
}

imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:postData scale:0.1];
```

You can compress with your required image size by using below code

```
NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, (double)(100-75)/100);
```

Above I have given 75.If you want to give your size,give there.